# Is there a way to improve readability of tailwind classnames in code?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

When using TailwindCSS, the `className` field easily stretches on the right, making it hard to read and edit.

Here is an example:

`className="group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30"`

A part of this most likely won't be visible if you have two windows on your editor.

Is there a VSCode or a CLI tool to indent this and improve readability?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has also bothered me when working with more complex classes, so I decided to create an [ESLint plugin](https://github.com/schoero/eslint-plugin-readable-tailwind) that provides fixes to automatically wrap long class names at a certain printWidth.

It can be installed via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-readable-tailwind):

```bash
npm i -D eslint-plugin-readable-tailwind
```

By default, it will convert long string literals to template literals, sort the classes logically, group them by modifiers and auto-wraps at a certain printWidth.

Your example code would get formatted like this:

```
<div className={`
  group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors

  hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700
  hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30
`} />
```

Every part of the plugin is configurable and it is designed work well with and without prettier.

If you set up ESLint to apply fixes on save, your classes will get automatically get formatted on save.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, In VS code just press `Alt + Z` basically its word wrap

or

In VC code, go to view there you enable word wrap

Answer (score 2):

1. First thing is to keep classes in order from more external to internal.
   Like Margin > Width / Height > Border > Padding etc...
2. Next step is to keep actions like :hover :visited after all from default state of element
3. Third step is to keep custom classes that are out of framework / core after all previous
4. And at end of class snake people keep classes which only purpose is to be js anchor (its not like i recommed it but see it quite often)

---

Many people don't like next step but from time to time you can see people keep long class / style list in vertical layout

In my opinion its way better for long elements to read classes but also cost a few bytes, and it make you see less of code at same time.

```
<html>
<body>
   <div className="
     group
     rounded-lg
     border
     border-transparent
     px-5
     py-4
     transition-colors
     hover:border-gray-300
     hover:bg-gray-100
     hover:dark:border-neutral-700
     hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30
     "
   >
      Content
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Worst way would be mix it like:

```
<html>
<body>
   <div className="
     group
     rounded-lg border border-transparent
     px-5 py-4
     transition-colors
     hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30
     "
   >
      Content
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Imo. its worst cause some lines can get wraped if they are too long and it would mess hierarchy.

Comment: Note that in a lot of code editors like VS Code the indentation won't get messed up when the lines are wrapped. So in a lot of cases the worst may not actually be the worst.